# Jenkins pipeline and conditional stages

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want add a condition on all stages:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'unix' }
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    when {branch 'master' }
    stages {
   
    }
}
```

I find any workaround with add `when` on each `steps` but I looking for a solution with only one `when`

```
stage('master-branch-stuff') {
    when {
        branch 'master'
    }
    steps {
        echo 'run this stage - ony if the branch = master branch'
    }
}
```

Comment: "all stages" meaning a stages subset, or an entire pipeline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be done this way

**declarative pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any;
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            when { branch 'master' }
            stages {
                stage('compile') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'compile'
                    }
                }
                stage('test') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'test'
                    }
                }
                stage('package') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'package'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**scripted pipeline**

```
def branch
node {
    stage('checkout') {
        def myScm = checkout scm
        branch = myScm['branch']
    }
    if(branch == 'master') {
      stage('compile') {
          echo "Compile"
      }
      stage('test') {
          echo "Test"
      }
      stage('package') {
          echo "Package"
      }
    } else {
        echo "don't do anything"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pure declarative pipeline, no.

Per their doc, https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when, `when` is only allowed "inside a stage directive."

```
stage {
  when { ... }
  ...
}
```

However, you can add stages within a `script` block. So you can do something like

```
stage {
  when { ... }
  steps {
    script {
        stage("scripted stage 1") { ... }
        stage("scripted stage 2") { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that everything inside of `script` (including the stages) will follow [scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline) rules